# Use Ruby with no-root user in Gentoo

Tags: ruby, git, gentoo

I am just started to update my Gitlab on Gentoo server (4.2 > 5.0). For new version Gitlab need to use Ruby with user 'git'.

```
# check ruby version for git user ( 1.9 required!! )
# gitlab shell requires system ruby 1.9
```

(https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/update/4.2-to-5.0.md)

I have Ruby installed, if I execute

```
ruby -v
```

with root user, it works fine

```
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-linux]
```

but when I am login as git

```
bash: ruby: Command not found
```

How can I make ruby available for git user?

Comment: Check how the `$PATH` variable is set for the user `git`, [here](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=5&style=printable) there is the doc about environment variables on Gentoo.

Comment: @toro2k I was try to change `$PATH` variable
`export PATH=$PATH:/root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin`
But it is did not workout. May be because of path /root?

Comment: @toro2k why don't you post that as an answer?